# Android Development - starting activity from service

Tags: android, email, exception

I've got a bit of code which is listening for a message on a socket, and parsing data from the socket into an email to be sent.  I'm able to create the intent, and set the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag on it, but yet, when i call
`startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email"));`

I get an AndoridRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

What confuses me on this is that I have explicitly called 
`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
protected void doEmail(DataInputStream in)  throws IOException {
  String id = in.readUTF();
  createEmail(id);
}

protected void createEmail(String rawEmailString) {
  // need to get to, subject, body and path from string
  String[] stringArray = rawEmailString.split("~");
  Intent intent = prepareEmail(stringArray[0], stringArray[1], stringArray[2], stringArray[3]);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email"));
}

public Intent prepareEmail(String to, String subject, String body, String pathToAttachment){
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(pathToAttachment));
  intent.setType("*/*");

  return intent;
}
```

Comment: That looks correct. Try just startActivity(intent) instead of using the chooser.

Comment: Thanks Robby, that helped move me in the right direction.  now it asks if i want to open with email or gmail.  it opens fine if i select gmail, but if i select email, it shows a dialog box reading "The application Email (process com.google.android.email) has stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again.  Is this syntax not supported by the standard email client?

Comment: Is an email account set up in the Email App?

Comment: it is.  I've been getting my email on it without issue for weeks.  I'm resetting it and trying to set it up again to see if that helps.

Comment: The other issue is that if i try and send from gmail, i can see the attachment, but i get an attachment error as soon as i send, and the email is sent without the file.  Not sure if these two issues are related or not.

Comment: @Jeff Are you trying to launch this activity from a background Service?

Comment: Aakash -  I am.  The service is largely a socket server listening for messages, and reacting to them

Answer (score 1):

The `Intent` you get back from `createChooser()` may not have your flag. Try adding it to the result of `createChooser()`.

Note that:

- Having a service pop up an activity is very unusual and should be able to be disabled by the user, as it can be very intrusive.
- Having a service pop up a chooser is lousy UX. Do you honestly think your users are going to have any idea what is going on when this "Email" chooser dialog appears out of nowhere?

Comment: CommonsWare -  I actually removed that, based on Robby's suggestion above, and as i noted, it gets further along now, but seems to be crashing the email app, or if i choose gmail, launching, but sending without the attachment.  The method currently reads
` protected void createEmail(String rawEmailString) {
 // need to get to, subject, body and path from string
  String[] stringArray = rawEmailString.split("~");
  Intent intent = prepareEmail(stringArray[0], stringArray[1], stringArray[2], stringArray[3]);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
 } `

Comment: @Jeff: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash. Presumably, those applications cannot read your attachment file.